# Javascript works in chrome, but not other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a countdown clock for an assignment. I asked my professor for help, but she was not able to help me. It works fine in Chrome, but in all other browsers is breaks and does not display the time.

here is the HTML, Javascript and CSS. It works here when I run the code, but it not working on Firefox, IE and etc.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(deadline) {
  var t = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, deadline) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining("2016-5-6 19:30:00 GMT+06:00");

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = '2016-5-6 19:30:00 GMT+06:00'; 
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: rgb(209,0,0);
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: white;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 
 
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Elly Belly Style</title>
<link href="npg_ebs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href = "npg_clock.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div id= "container">


 <h2>Countdown to the next Auction</h2>
 <div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
</section> <!-- end main column -->

 
</section> 

</div>

<footer>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.htm" title="Homepage">Elly Belly Style</a></li>
  <!-- <li><a href="http://ellybelly.bigcartel.com/" title="Ready To Ship">Ready To Ship</a></li> commented out for project-->
  <li><a href="npg_rts.htm" title="Ready To Ship">Ready to Ship</a></li> 
  <!-- <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/ebsupcycles/" title="Elly Wars Auctions">Elly Wars Auctions</a></li> commented out for project-->
  <li><a href="npg_ellywars.htm" title="Elly Wars Auctions">Elly Wars</a></li> 
  <li><a href="npg_pictures.htm" title="Completed Designs">Completed Designs</a></li>
  <li><a href="npg_about.htm" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="npg_custom.htm" title="Custom Order Inquiry">Custom Order Inquiry</a></li>
  <li><a href="npg_links.htm" title="Links">Links</a></li> 
  <li><a href="npg_design.htm" title="Design Document">Design Document</a></li> 
  <li><a href="npg_table.htm" title="Business Hours">Business Hours</a></li>
  <li><a href="npg_sitemap.htm" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
  <li><img src="npg_mail.png" alt="email"/>Email:
   <script language="JavaScript"> <!--
    document.write ('<A HREF="mai')
    document.write ('lto:ellybellybows')
    document.write ('&#64;')
    document.write ('gmail.com">ellybellybows')
    document.write ('&#64;')
    document.write ('gmail.com</A>')
    // email link hidden-->
   </script>
  </li>
</ul>

</footer>

<script>
//script for dropdown button
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<script src="npg_clock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code debugging service. If you want help you need to show that you're willing to put in an effort. Dumping a bunch of code and saying "it doesn't work" is akin to asking us to work for free. Please update your code to be a [mcve], otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: My apologizes, I am obviously new to all of this, including this community. I would not have turned to help from other's if my professor had been able to help me. I have run the debugger in Firefox with nothing showing up as flagged. The clock in all other browsers shows NaN = Days aN = Hours aN=minutes and aN=seconds.

Comment: Please don't remove your code just because you have been given an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is the incorrect formatting of Date string, follow the [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format, use: `2016-05-06T19:30:00+06:00`.

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mido22/adsrmtyL/) of the fixed code.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @LokisCoyote hey since your problem has been solved, would you mind editing your question to include more relevant info? like what's the problem, what have you tried, plus any helpful code snippets. It will help others who have a similar problem in the future and stumble across your question. Also, it'll just be good practice :)